# scrapy sitemap spider does not provide expected results

Tags: scrapy, sitemap

I have this nested sitemap. Scrapy docs say it is supposed to work with nested sitemaps without any problem.
My target links are like this one https://flatinfo.ru/arenda_kvartir.asp?id=867039

So in my understanding my `sitemap_rules` , conaining the keyword from the link (`'/arenda_kvartir/'`) should make the spider behave in the following logic:
all links, found in the `sitemap.xml` and containing keyword from `sitemap_rules` should be scraped into `parsed` function. But this never happens according to the logs. The spider just goes through all major categories in the sitemap and quits. 
Where am I wrong?
Below is my code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider

class CodeSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'code_s'
    sitemap_urls = ['https://flatinfo.ru/sitemap.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [
        ('/arenda_kvartir/', 'parsed'),
        ('/sitemap_prodaja_kvartir/', 'parsed'),
    ] 


    def parsed(self, response):
        yield {

                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match two type of URLs in your `sitemap_rules`: `https://flatinfo.ru/arenda.asp?house=43182` and `https://flatinfo.ru/prodaja_kvartir.asp?id=17488515`. The **correct** `sitemap_rules` will be:

```
sitemap_rules = [
    ('arenda.asp', 'parsed'),
    ('prodaja_kvartir.asp', 'parsed'),
]
sitemap_follow = ['sitemap_prodaja_kvartir', 'sitemap_arenda']
```

(I added `sitemap_follow` to skip other sitemap entries).

One more thing: you need to wait (almost 20 minutes till the first processed URL for me!) because each XML file takes a lot of time to process.

Comment: could you elaborate on your solution please. How is prodaja_kvartir different from prodaja_kvartir.asp? both keywords are present in the url. The entire workaround time is less then 10 minutes with thread count = 1, wait 3 sec, and no errors.

Comment: You don't have `prodaja_kvartir` in your code (it works) but `/prodaja_kvartir/` (searching for a **string** `/prodaja_kvartir/` in each URL) that's why your code doesn't work.